# Spark of the array manifold of a random antenna array

Tags: matlab, compressive-sensing, sparsity

let's consider I have an antenna array with N-elements, and its sensors are not placed in a uniform linear array fashion (may be randomly placed, a coprime array, or a nested array, for example). What would the spark of the corresponding dictionary array manifold be? We know that Vandermonde matrices can be considered to be full spark, since the abovementioned arrays do not render a Vandermonde structure of the dictionary manifold, how can the spark be calculated?

P.S: I have tried using the concept of mutual coherence which does not help at all for my problem.